# How to reload a package when it is installed in editable mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that to reload a package installed with e.g. `pip install .` you can

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(module)
```

but this approach does not seem to work when the package is installed with `pip install -e .`.

Is there any way to reload a package when it is installed in editable mode?